# structure of query does not match function result type

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a basic function which takes an input and throws a table with multiple columns and rows as an output . I have written the following query for the same :

```
create or replace function proc_name_1 (store text)
returns table (question text , resp numeric , gendr text , resp_count integer) 
as $$
begin 
return query 
select question_type , response, gender, sum(response_count) 
from fashtagcompute.response_count
where store_id = store 
group by question_type , response, gender ;  
end ; 
$$ 
language plpgsql ; 

CREATE FUNCTION
```

The function is succesfully created. However if I try and execute  it , I get the following error

```
select * from proc_name_1('ab1f47ff-5c96-46fb-b975-81bf92c01b63')

ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type 
DETAIL: Returned type character varying(80) does not match expected type text in column 1. 
CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function proc_name_1(text) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: The error message, if you read it, tells you exactly what the problem is. So, what's your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that `question_type` is defined as **varchar(80)** but you as defined `question` as **text**.

Simply cast it as text:

```
select question_type::text
```